# StencliJS get ref of child component

Tags: jsx, ref, stenciljs

I have a parent component and a child component. The child component creates form input fields with dynamic refs to get the value or to validate like this:

```
  private buildTextField(formElement:FormBuilderElement):HTMLInputElement {
    return <input type="text"
      name={formElement.name}
      id={formElement.name}
      value=""
      required={formElement.required}
      ref={(el) => this[`${formElement.name}_ref`] = el as HTMLInputElement} />
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Host>
        {
          this.formElements.map((fe) => (
                <div>
                  <div>{this.buildInput(fe)}</div>
                </div>
          ))
        }
      </Host>
    );
  }
```

this.formElements is a Prop that is passed in from the parent. You see the ref is dynamically created from the name property of the FormBuilderElement.
In the child component I can just reference the ref with this[`${dynamicName}_ref`] and I get the HTMLInputElement perfectly.

Now this child component is created in a parent component render like this:

```
  render() {
    return (
      <Host>
        <div>
            {
            
              <my-form formElements={this.formElements} ref={(el) =>  this.myformchild = el as HTMLElement} ></my-form>
            }
        </div>
      </Host>
    );
  }
```

You see I have added a ref to my-form also. So now I want to get the HTMLInputElements from the my-form child component by their refs. So I would have thought this should work but I just get **undefined**:

```
const requiredElement = this.myformchild [`${dynamicName}_ref`];
```

**What is the correct way to reference refs specified in a child component?**

Answer (score 0):

In the end we added an @Method in the child component to get a reference to the class which gave us all the ref variables. So add a reference to the child component, call a method to get an instance of the class:

Parent reference

```
<my-form formElements={this.formElements} ref={(el) =>  this.myformchild = el as HTMLElement} ></my-form>
```

Child component method

```
  @Method() 
  async getForm(){
    return this;
  }
```

Then the parent calling it, must be in an async block or method

```
const form = this.myformchild.getForm();
const inputElement = form[`${dynamicName}_ref`]
```